# How to access private members of other template class instances?

Tags: c++, templates, private-members

This extremely minimal example will fail to compile because `A<int>` cannot access the private member `i` in `A<double>`

```
template <class T>
class A {
    int i;
  public:
    template <class U>
    void copy_i_from( const A<U> & a ){
        i = a.i;
    }
};

int main(void) {
    A<int> ai;
    A<double> ad;
    ai.copy_i_from(ad);
    return 0;
}
```

I cannot find the correct way to make those template instances friends.

Comment: `A<int>` and `A<double>` are completely different classes. Consequently, rightfully they can't access mutually each others private members.

Comment: @40two Sure, the point is how to let them with some kind of friend declaration.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
template <class T>
class A {
    template<class U>
    friend class A;
    int i;
  public:
    template <class U>
    void copy_i_from( const A<U> & a ){
        i = a.i;
    }
};

int main(void) {
    A<int> ai;
    A<double> ad;
    ai.copy_i_from(ad);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you think that is possible to make friend only the method?